# Is this a group when including the origin

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, complex-numbers, abelian-groups

Considering $(a,b)*(c,d)=(ac-bd,ad+bc)$ on the set $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ including the origin, would this be a group? I solved for the commutative prop, associative prop, identity and inverses when we did not include the origin but concluded that that was not a group because I wasn't able to solve for inverses. I would conclude from my previous results that this would also not be a group because I still wouldn't have inverses, especially since zero can now be used.

Comment: It's not a group if we count the origin

Comment: The identity is $(1, 0)$, while $(0, 0) \ast (c, d) = (0, 0)$ always, so....

Comment: Unless I'm much mistaken, it is a group when you don't count the origin.

Comment: $(a,b)^{-1}=\left(\frac{a}{a^2+b^2},-\frac{b}{a^2+b^2}\right)$. This works for all $(a,b)$ except $(0,0)$.

Comment: Note that when you multiply by any element in a group the operation is a bijection (fix a group element g, then the map defined by "x goes to gx" is a bijection). When you multiply by zero, it is very much not a bijection.

Answer (score 1):

"I would conclude from my previous results that this would also not be a group because I still wouldn't have inverses, especially since zero can now be used."

Precisely.

To be a group there would be a distinct element $e$ so that $e(a,b) = (a,b)$ for all $(a,b)$.  If there is such a value (and there is) it is obvious *not* $(0,0)$ as $(0,0)(a,b) = (0,0) \ne (a,b)$.

And there would be a distinct element $(0,0)^{-1} = (f,g)$ so that $(0,0)(0,0)^{-1} = (0,0)(f,g) =  e$.  But whatever possible values $(f,g)$ is $(0,0)(f,g) = (0,0)$ and, again, $(0,0)$ is obviously *not* the identity.

So $(0,0)$ has no inverse and thus this can not be a group.

However... If we omit $(0,0)$ from this, $\mathbb R\times \mathbb R\setminus \{(0,0)\}, *$ *is* a group.

$e = (1,0)$ yields $(1,0)(a,b) = (a - 0*b, 0*a + 1*b) = (a,b)$ acts as an identity.  $(1,0)$ can be shown to be unique in this regard. And for every $(a,b)$ where $a$ and $b$ do not both equal $0$ the value $(\frac a {a^2 + b^2}, -\frac b{a^2 + b^2})$ is well defined (because $a^2 + b^2 \ne 0$) and $(a,b)(\frac a {a^2 + b^2}, -\frac b{a^2 + b^2}) = (1,0)$, so $(\frac a {a^2 + b^2}, -\frac b{a^2 + b^2})$ *is* an inverse element for any $(a,b)$.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly $(\mathbb{C}^*,\cdot)$ with multiplication law defined in ordinary sense:

$$(a+bi)\cdot(c+di)=(ac-bd,ad+bc).$$

---

we can't define a group law on $(\mathbb{C},\cdot)$ .

Comment: Did you just ignore the comments while misreading the question?

Comment: There are uncountable groups. **Edit:** Sorry, but... if you mean the standard product, then it doesn't even make sense to mention that we can't make $(\mathbb C, \cdot)$ a group, because it simply isn't, $\mathbb C$ is defined and so is the product.